# Simplifying a bitwise operation

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have the following bitwise expression and was wondering if it could be simplified or if there is a general way of interpreting the output.

```
(x & y) | (~x & ~y)
```

Comment: What operations can you use? Logically it's the same as `NOT(XOR(x, y))`

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

The only "simpler" version is `~(x^y)` (where `^` is the XOR operator).

However, It's not going to make a significant difference computationally, and is harder to read for most people (XOR is not as natural as AND and OR). There's not a simpler version using just AND and OR operators, so I would suggest you just leave it as-is.

> if there is a general way of interpreting the output.

"Either both are true or both are false" is a natural interpretation.